# Solving $2 \sin^2x + 6 \sin^2 \frac 12x = 3$

Tags: trigonometry

> $$
> 2 \sin^2x + 6 \sin^2 \frac 12x = 3
> $$
>   Find the angles between $0^{\circ}$ and $360^{\circ}$ which satisfy the equation above.

So, I found the answers by inputting all the possible special angles; $60^{\circ}$ and $120^{\circ}$ worked.

> Are there any other ways to find the answers, and are there more than the two answers that I found?

Comment: $\sin^2 x = (1-\cos^2 x), \sin^2 \frac 12 x = \frac 12(1-\cos x)$  apply these two identities and you have a quadratic in terms of $\cos x$

Comment: Check $120$ again,  and what about $-60$?

Comment: $\sin 120 = \sin 60$ right? doesn't that mean that it's possible? I checked it again too and it gave the answer 3

Comment: yeah, I just checked - 60 $^{\circ}$ which is equal to 300 $^{\circ}$ is also one of the answer. from the answer's and comments's on the cos equation. but i didn't find 120 as the answer from the cos equation

Comment: Did I do a miscount somewhere ? ;-;

Comment: never mind I did a miscount. It should be 6 not 3 @Doug M thankss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Recall that

- $\sin^2 \frac x 2 =\frac12-\frac12 \cos x$
- $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$

therefore

$$2 \sin^2x + 6 \sin^2 \frac x 2 = 3\iff 2-2\cos^2x+3-3\cos x=3 \iff2\cos^2x+3\cos x-2=0$$

Comment: to find the angles, i need to find the roots of the quadratic fuction right? I found that $(\cos x + 2) (2\cos x - 1)$ are the roots and those roots mean that $cos x = - 2$ and $cos x = \frac 12$. Is x = 60 / x = 300 ?

Comment: @Audrey Yes exactly, the only possible root is $\cos x=1/2 \implies x=60°$ and $x=300°$.

Comment: But I also tried using 120$^{\circ}$ and it also fits the equation... @gimusi Did I perhaps miscount somewhere ... ;-;

Comment: @AudreyNote that for x=120° we obtain $$2 \sin^2(120°) + 6 \sin^2 60° =\frac32+\frac92=6\neq 3$$

Comment: oh yeahhh I forgot to time 3 >~< . Okay I did miscount ;((( thx

Answer (score 0):

$2 \sin^2x + 6 \sin^2 \frac 12x = 3$

$2(1-\cos^2(x))+6\cdot\dfrac12\cdot(1-\cos(x)) = 3$

let  $\cos(x) = z$

$2(1-z^2) +3(1-z) = 3$

$2-2z^2+3-3z = 3$

$2z^2+3z-2 =0$

Solving the above quadratic and substituting back $z =\cos(x)$ will give you the solutions.